# Extract text with selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to return the text 'My name is' from this code. The text can change so I can't use it in the element locator.

```
<span class="tabComboBoxName" id="tab-ui-id-1607647" aria-hidden="true">My name is</span>
```

My ultimate goal is to compare this text to a variable which I have figured out, but first I need to extract the text.

Any idea on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

To extract the text *My name is* you can use either of the following [java](/questions/tagged/java) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.tabComboBoxName[id^='tab-ui-id-']")).getText());
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='tabComboBoxName' and starts-with(@id, 'tab-ui-id-')]")).getText());
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the  `visibilityOfElementLocated()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *xpath*:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("span.tabComboBoxName[id^='tab-ui-id-']"))).getText());
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[@class='tabComboBoxName' and starts-with(@id, 'tab-ui-id-')]"))).getText());
  ```